# RecyclerView + HidingScrollListener + Load More

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, endlessscroll

I use hiding scroll listener with `recyclerview`. When I scroll down `recyclerview` and release scroll, if loads more and add new contents to adapter with item range inserted my rows previously added or new added not responding to click. But when I scroll again a little bit all my click tries works.

Here is my `HidingScrollListener`:

```
public abstract class HidingScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

   private static final float HIDE_THRESHOLD = 10;
   private static final float SHOW_THRESHOLD = 70;

   private int                 mToolbarOffset   = 0;
   private boolean             mControlsVisible = true;
   private int                 mToolbarHeight;
   private int                 mTotalScrolledDistance;
   private int                 previousTotal    = 0;
   private boolean             loading          = true;
   private int                 visibleThreshold = 4;
   int                         firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
   private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

   public HidingScrollListener(Context context, LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
      mToolbarHeight = Tools.getFooterHeight(context);
      this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
   }

   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
      super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

      if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
         if (mTotalScrolledDistance < mToolbarHeight) {
            setVisible();
         }
         else {
            if (mControlsVisible) {
               if (mToolbarOffset > HIDE_THRESHOLD) {
                  setInvisible();
               }
               else {
                  setVisible();
               }
            }
            else {
               if ((mToolbarHeight - mToolbarOffset) > SHOW_THRESHOLD) {
                  setVisible();
               }
               else {
                  setInvisible();
               }
            }
         }
      }

   }

   @Override
   public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

      clipToolbarOffset();
      onMoved(mToolbarOffset);

      if ((mToolbarOffset < mToolbarHeight && dy > 0) || (mToolbarOffset > 0 && dy < 0)) {
         mToolbarOffset += dy;
      }
      if (mTotalScrolledDistance < 0) {
         mTotalScrolledDistance = 0;
      }
      else {
         mTotalScrolledDistance += dy;
      }
      // for load more
      visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
      totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
      firstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

      if (loading) {
         if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
         }
      }
      if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
         // End has been reached
         // Do something

         loading = true;
         onLoadMore();
      }
   }

   private void clipToolbarOffset() {
      if (mToolbarOffset > mToolbarHeight) {
         mToolbarOffset = mToolbarHeight;
      }
      else if (mToolbarOffset < 0) {
         mToolbarOffset = 0;
      }
   }

   private void setVisible() {
      if (mToolbarOffset > 0) {
         onShow();
         mToolbarOffset = 0;
      }
      mControlsVisible = true;
   }

   private void setInvisible() {
      if (mToolbarOffset < mToolbarHeight) {
         onHide();
         mToolbarOffset = mToolbarHeight;
      }
      mControlsVisible = false;
   }

   public abstract void onMoved(int distance);

   public abstract void onShow();

   public abstract void onHide();

   public abstract void onLoadMore();
}
```

and `onLoadMore()`:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(size, data.size());
```

I cannot figure out why this's happening. It's very strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is i notify wrong range when i try to use `notifyItemRangeChanged()` method of my `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

This causes to block Ui Thread so i cannot get any action onClick before i interrupt the ui thread.

When i set a valid item range for notify adapter, this got fixed.

I hope my answer'll help someone.

Correct call is below:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(size+1, data.size());
```